# simple regex pattern confusion

Tags: php, regex

Somebody give me a hand please. Why I am getting the below output

```
$pattern = "#([a-z])*|(chol)#";
preg_match($pattern, 'chol',$m);

print_r($m) // array
                (
                  [0]=> 'chol',
                  [1]=> 'l'
                )
```

why is the first sub capture matched is only `l` character while the full match is `chol`. May be I am missing something. 
I expected this output below

```
array
        (
         [0]=> 'chol',
         [1]=> 'chol'
        )
```

I don't think the pattern is overly complicated to confuse me.

Comment: I guess you want to further manipulate the results in a `preg_replace_callback`. See my answer below, it explains why you need to  quantify the atom inside the group and not the group itself, and that the order of the alternations is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You quantified a group. You need to quantify the `[a-z]` character class.

Use

```
$pattern = "#([a-z]*)|(chol)#";
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/mlhHQ6) and more details at [*Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). In short: the `([a-z]*)` will match and capture 0 or more lowercase ASCII letters into Group 1 and it will contain the whole chunk of these letters, while `([a-z])*` will match and capture 0 or more occurrences of consequent lowercase ASCII letter, while overwriting each previous occurrence with a new one.

You might also consider removing the redundant capturing groups if you are not using them.

More, since this is an unanchored alternation, note that `[a-z]*` will always match `chol` and the second alternative will never match. You might consider putting `(chol)` as the *first alternative* as it is *more specific*.

So, I suggest

```
$pattern = "#(chol)|([a-z]*)#";
```

More on this at [Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).

Comment: Does that explain this behaviour?

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic Yes, it does.

Comment: Actually, my original intent was to test effects of groups on pattern 
 with alternations. I never though much about them

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic See my update. I think the order of the groups is important here.

Comment: what happens with pattern with alternatives and with each having groups, but the last only matches. Does the matches array contain empty groups from unmatched first alternatives

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic PHP removes the unmatched groups (those that did not participate in the match).